# git.exe is not found by gradle

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle, git-bash, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My Android Studio project uses git from gradle :

```
branchName = ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
                    exec {
                        commandLine("git branch --show-current")
                        standardOutput = outputStream
                    }
                    outputStream.toString()
                }
```

On Linux and Mac, this works just fine, but on Windows it says:

> Could not start 'git'

and I have to replace it with this :

```
commandLine("cmd", "/c", "git branch --show-current")
```

this defeats the purpose for me since I want this to work on different platforms and machines. If I add it it'll instead break on Linux and Mac.
any suggestions on what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do an OS checking this way

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// ...

branchName = ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
                    exec {
                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) commandLine("cmd", "/c", "git branch --show-current")
                        else commandLine("git branch --show-current")
                        standardOutput = outputStream
                    }
                    outputStream.toString()
                }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason? I understand that it adds a few lines, but if your target dev envs are Windows, Linux and Mac, I'd say this is a pretty neat hack.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the branch name and avoid using command line ?

Comment: I'd suggest to look for a native git plugin for gradle and maybe work from there? [grgit](https://github.com/ajoberstar/grgit) is a gradle plugin that uses JGit to perform git operations. I have not tried this yet, but I hope this inspired you to look for more.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to make it only in linux way, you can give a try for WSL -
[Windows Subsytem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Here is an additional [instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201230) for run Android Studio with this.

It works but require some configuration, but generally it will be a bit overkill for your case and I think @deecue is right sugesting small if - look at documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

You can just do it in a bit more pleasant and reusable way - as an extracted method:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// ...

fun runCommand(command: String, windowsDir: String = "/c") {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine("cmd", windowsDir, command)
    } else {
        commandLine(command)
    }
}

// ...

branchName = ByteArrayOutputStream().use { outputStream ->
    exec {
        runCommand("git branch --show-current")
        standardOutput = outputStream
    }
    outputStream.toString()
}
```

Comment: I already did this, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you also restart your ide/terminal? It could would crazy but try also restart windows to make sure, that path is up to date

Comment: Actually I did restart the windows but it didnt help.